# hoe can i get xml from a big xml?

Tags: linq-to-xml, xquery

i have a xml field in my table and my table is same this :

```
id | xml |
```

no i have a record same this :

```
 <dfs>

 <field mainType="text" id="cce267e046a57c1"></field>
 <field mainType="text" id="1b2490d1b11967c1"></field>
 <moduleFields mainType="module" many="true" moduleId="5" id="4a191594ec2c8723">
 <items>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_1_56e5290262cd1eef"></field>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_1_f311896a52011eef"></field>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_1_e68f6673b9c79eef">1</field>
 </items>
 <items>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_2_56e5290262cd1eef"></field>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_2_f311896a52011eef">2</field>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_2_e68f6673b9c79eef">2</field>
 </items>
 <items>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_3_56e5290262cd1eef">3</field>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_3_f311896a52011eef">3</field>
   <field mainType="text" id="4a191594ec2c8723_3_e68f6673b9c79eef">3</field>
 </items>
 </moduleFields>
 </dfs>
```

how i can get moduleFields sub tag ?

whith linq to xml or xquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and S[electSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) if you only want to have the moduleFields element and then iterate of its [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx)

// assume xmField is a string that holds your xml from th dbfield.

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlField));
var module = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/dfs/moduleFields");
if (module!=null) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("value:" + module.Value);
    foreach(var attr in module.Attributes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(attr.Name + "=" + attr.Value);
    }
}
else
{
  Debug.WriteLine("modulefields not found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this query**:

```
/*/moduleFields
```

This selects any `moduleFields` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**In case there is more than one `moduleFields` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document, and you need to obtain only the first such `moduleFields` element, then use**:

```
/*/moduleFields[1]
```